# How can I sum compared values in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Glanced gnuplot [book](https://www.manning.com/books/gnuplot-in-action-second-edition) but couldn't found like this comparison and sum example. if I think rightly not many people need it.

I have to sum comparison results among themselves(bound) and plot as a column. For example; I have to sum these `26` of comparison result plot as a column then sum `86` of comparison result as another bar pillar.
I don't have following `0` or `1` value, I want to compare and add gnuplot before plotting the bar chart. We can skip this step for now cause I made another program comparison, but summation should be by gnuplot.

I have explained first step so far.
Moreover, I have a thousand 26, 86, 12,... whatever. I need a loop which sum those thousands and sum next thousand till 70000. I need just look these thousands as one thing like as pillar in whole graph for comparison.

Could you help?

| S_index | F_index | Comparison Result | Bound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 26 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 26 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 26 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 26 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 26 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 26 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 26 |
| 0 | 3 | 0 | 26 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 26 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 26 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 26 |
| 0 | 3 | 0 | 86 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 86 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 86 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 86 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 86 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | 86 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 86 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 86 |
| 0 | 3 | 0 | 86 |

Added data which sample of the `csv` file

```
2,0,28
 2,1,28
 0,3,28
 2,1,28
 3,3,28
 1,3,28
 1,1,28
 1,0,28
 2,2,28
 2,3,28
 0,1,28
 1,2,28
 0,3,28
 0,0,28
2,3,88
 2,2,88
 3,2,88
 3,2,88
 1,3,88
 2,2,88
 3,0,88
 1,3,88
 3,3,88
 0,0,88
 2,0,88
 1,2,88
 0,1,88
 3,0,88
 3,0,88
1,3,110
 1,2,110
 1,3,110
 3,2,110
 2,2,110
 0,0,110
 3,3,110
 3,2,110
 2,0,110
 2,1,110
 0,1,110
 2,0,110
 0,3,110
 0,2,110
 3,2,110
 0,3,110
 1,0,110
 2,1,110
 1,3,110
 1,3,110
 2,3,110
 3,1,110
 0,0,110
 2,1,110
 1,0,110
 0,1,110
 1,1,110
 3,3,110
 0,1,110
 1,3,110
```

```
### sum up for certain conditions
reset session

set offset 0,0,0.5,0    # <left>,<right>,<top>,<bottom>
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid 0.5

set table $SumUp
    plot "boundary.csv" u 3:($1==$2) smooth freq
unset table

set yrange[0:]
set grid x,y

plot $SumUp u 0:2:xtic(1) w boxes title "Sum"

### end of code
```

getting error

```
plot "boundary.csv" u 3:($1==$2) smooth freq
                                            ^
         "gnuplot.gp" line 9: x range is invalid
```

```
gnuplot -v

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.4 patchlevel 1    last modified 2020-12-01 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2020
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type is now 'qt'
unrecognized option -v
```

Comment: I'm confused by your description and I don't understand what you really want to have. What I think I understood: you have 2 columns with many values (what do you mean with 1k by 1k?). If the values in col1 and col2 are equal sum them up. What do you mean with "summarize data under 100 because is 70k"? Furthermore, is your file extension really `.cvs` or maybe `.csv`? What do you actually want to plot? Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @theozh I fixed, hope bit clear. sorry for confusion

Comment: sorry, still not clear. So, there are 70000 values in your table and 1000 with identical values in column3 and you want to sum up the values of column1 and column2 but only if they are equal? And then plot this sum these sums versus column3? Sorry, I don't think I got it.

Comment: @theozh no problem, on the contrary my writing ability terrible and hasty, feel free please :). Actually I'm looking true matches and count them then plot them. I need to see to summary which possible 1000. Plotting third column different curve, but I need to plot over canvas just checking exact range. `Column 3` counts thousands.

Comment: I'm confused more and more. Please describe what you want in your native language and use some translator webpage to English and paste it here. Maybe then we will come closer to understand what your goal should be. Or maybe make a sketch to illustrate what you want. I still don't have any idea.

Comment: @theozh I rewrite explanation and added new column to the data table. Could you glance? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure whether I understood what you are looking for.
The following code is summing up (counting) how many times column1 is equal column2, and does this separately for each value in column3. In the gnuplot console check `help smooth`, `help table`.

**Code:**

```
### sum up for certain conditions
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   1   26   # <-- will be summed up
0   1   26
1   1   26   # <-- will be summed up
3   3   26   # <-- will be summed up
2   1   26
1   0   26
1   1   86   # <-- will be summed up
0   0   86   # <-- will be summed up
2   1   86
1   3   86
3   1   86
1   0   86
0   1   12
3   3   12   # <-- will be summed up
3   2   12
2   2   12   # <-- will be summed up
0   0   12   # <-- will be summed up
1   1   12   # <-- will be summed up
EOD

set offset 0,0,0.5,0    # <left>, <right>, <top>, <bottom>
set boxwidth 0.8
set style fill solid 0.5

set table $SumUp
    plot $Data u 3:($1==$2) smooth freq
unset table

set yrange[0:]
set grid x,y

plot $SumUp u 0:2:xtic(1) w boxes title "Sum"

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: What does do `plot $SumUp u 0:2:xtic(1) w boxes title "Sum"` this line cause need to plot form `csv` file? Cause I want to call the plot form directly `C` code. Actually, I used `help  xtic` but shows `xticlabels and xtics`.

Comment: I changed just the line of  `plot "boundary.csv" u 3:($1==$2) smooth freq` but got ` I changed just the line of  `plot "boundary.csv" u 3:($1==$2) smooth freq` but got `plot "boundary.csv" u 3:($1==$2) smooth freq
                                                                                                                  ^
           "gnuplot.gp" line 9: x range is invalid
`How can I fix this
` can I fix this?

Comment: @maxemilian how does your data actually look like? What is your column separator?  I assume comma if you have a `.csv` file.  Please show some real data formatted as code (not as table). I would assume that you have to insert the line `set datafile separator comma`.

Comment: `2,1,30  
 0,1,30  
 0,0,30`  My data looks like that in `csv` file.  Yeah I did my gnuplot code above but `set datafile separator ','` like this

Comment: @maxemilian so, still getting `x range is invalid`? Please edit your question and post the _exact_ code you are using. Which gnuplot version are you running?

Comment: I did below of the first post

Comment: @maxemilian then something must be "wrong" with your data. Can you maybe somehow provide the data? What is your language setting for decimal sign, comma or point? What is the result if you type `show decimal`?

Comment: I added. All data an `int` format printed with `%d` command. Where I enter `show decimal` command? Didn't understand

Comment: @maxemilian ok, now I see the problem. Because you have comma as separator, but the table `$Sumup` is written with whitespace as separator (not comma). So, you have insert `set datafile separator comma` before the table command and `set datafile separator whitespace` before the final plot command.